# Implement getElementByClassName from scratch using recursion

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, dom, getelementsbyclassname

I have a prompt to build a function that is getElementByClassName, using `document.body`, `element.classList`, and `element.childNodes` AND recursion.
This is what I have :

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className
) {
  var classNameArray = [];
  var bodyElement = document.body;
  var traverseTheNode = function(elementNode) {
    if (elementNode.classList.contains(className)) {
      classNameArray.push(elementNode);
    }
    elementNode.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (node.classList === undefined) {
        return;
      } else if (node.classList.contains(className)) {
        classNameArray.push(node);
      } else {
        return traverseTheNode(node);
      }
    });
  }
};

console.log(getElementsByClassName('targetClassName'))
```

The code does what I want it to but when I console.log, it throws an error. "cannot read property of classList of null" talking about the first if statement. Any ideas?

Comment: I stuck your function in a snippet and tested with a few different html configurations - they all worked. Can you post the HTML you're testing it against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different issue. Your array was not returning all instances of a class, just one. I reorganized your if statements so that it would traverse the children of a node before the other conditions and it seems to now be returning all matching nodes.

```js
var getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
  var classNameArray = [];
  var bodyElement = document.body;
  var traverseTheNode = function(elementNode) {
    if (elementNode.classList.contains(className)) {
      classNameArray.push(elementNode);
    }
    elementNode.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        return traverseTheNode(node);
      } else if (node.classList === undefined) {
        return;
      } else if (node.classList.contains(className)) {
        classNameArray.push(node);
      }


    });
  }
  traverseTheNode(bodyElement);
  //console.log(classNameArray)
  return classNameArray;
};

console.log(getElementsByClassName('three'))
```

```html
<div class='three'>
  <ul class="two">
    <li>Hmmm
      <dd class='three'>
      </dd>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: wow. I can't believe how close I was. spent the better half of entire day on this, maybe i shoulda taken a break ha. Thanks man, looks great!

Answer (score 0):

This translates the above to a more functional style:

```js
const gebcn = (className) => (element) => 
  (Array .from (element .classList || []) .includes (className)
    ? [element] 
    : []
  ).concat (
    element .hasChildNodes() 
      ? Array .from (element .childNodes) .flatMap (gebcn (className))
      : []
  )
  
const getElementsByClassName = (className) => gebcn (className) (document .body)

console.log (getElementsByClassName ('three'))
```

```html
<div class='three'>
  <ul class="two">
    <li>Hmmm
      <dd class='three'>
      </dd>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

We write a more general-purpose version, `gebcn`, which finds all the elements with a given class name *inside a particular element*.  Then we write `getElementsByClassName` on top of this, defaulting the target element with `document.body`.

Our main function simply tests the current element to see whether it has the correct class, placing it in a single-element array if so or yielding an empty array otherwise, and then recurs on any `childNodes`, `flatMap`ping them into a single array.